# IIS 10 website running an ASP.NET Core MVC app only returns 500 Error

Tags: asp.net-core, iis, http-status-code-500

I have (tried to) set up an ASP.NET Core MVC app on IIS 10 and I'm getting a 500 - Internal Server Error trying to access it through the browser.

I have installed the .NET Core bundle [from microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/iis/hosting-bundle?view=aspnetcore-6.0).

My application pool is using "No Managed Code" and the pipeline mode is integrated.

I have published the website as a self contained application from Visual Studio.

If I attempt to change any settings for the site from IIS, I get the following error

> There was an error while performing this operation.
>
> Details:
>
> Filename: \?\C:\inetpub\wwwroot\foldername\web.config

I cannot get a more detailed error to show than just `500` since I cannot open the "Error Pages" settings.

Those errors stop occurring if I remove the `aspNetCore` tag from `web.config`, but then obviously the website doesn't load. I can add the detailed error pages manually to the `web.config` file, but they don't appear to do anything.

`stdoutLogEnabled` is set to true and IIS_IUSR has write access to the folder it's pointing at, but there is nothing in the folder being logged. Nor is there anything included in the event log.

The only logs of any activity are in the `C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC2` folder, showing the 500 responses to the requests.

I was able to get the website to load, by just running the executable in the folder and no server errors are reported in the console

This same website (un)fortunately runs without error from Visual Studio and on a different IIS installation on another server.

Comment: If you run a report then the cause should be clear, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ancm-diagnostics.html

Comment: Can you show the full error page of 500?

Comment: @BruceZhang It was just the regular 500 error page, no extra information. I have solved the issue and posted what I'd mucked up in an answer

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the issue.

I was using the ASP.NET Core Hosting Bundle version 5.0.0, since I seemingly wrongly assumed that was the one for .NET 5.

I updated that to version 6.0.0, and that converted the error page to `HTTP Error 500.32 - Failed to load .NET Core host` and an entry in the event log.

The event log entry stated:

> Unable to load 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\foldername.\hostfxr.dll'. This  might be caused by a bitness mismatch between IIS application pool
> and published application.

So I changed the `Enable 32-Bit Applications` setting of the Application Pool and between updating the bundle and changing that setting, something worked.

Comment: Consider deploying a 64-bit version of your web app instead.

Comment: @CodeCaster The web app was 64 bit, I'd set Enable 32-Bit Applications to true assuming that it mean 'enable' rather than 'force' 32 bit.